# HTAP architecture of gridDB

Tags: database, griddb

How does GridDB's use of hybrid transaction/analytical processing (HTAP) architecture impact its ability to handle large-scale data processing and real-time analytics in distributed environments compared to traditional transactional databases?

I am reading girdDB's official documentation but wanting to have some experienced people to advise their points on it.